# Setting up a proxy for java webstart applications

Tags: java, proxy, java-web-start

We've decided to use webstart for deploying some of our applications. The problem is, another company will be using our application for quite a number of different employees. Is there any way to have another server be a proxy for our webstart so that they don't need to download the application from our servers more than once? Of course, I'm also wanting the proxy to download changes as users launch the application.

```
e3  -----------\

e2  ------------|webstart proxy ------------ webstart

e1  -----------/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Just an answer if some-body has the same problem..
```

You can on your dns redirect the url of the java-webstart to a local server-ip.

In this approach you still need to update the files on both server, but for that you can use any sync-tool..

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of such a beast.

You can, however, setup a local copy of your application on an internal server and use rsync to keep the copy updated.

Alternatively, use DropBox to create a web presence of the files.  Then DropBox takes the traffic hit.